# PNG Transparency in cocos2d iphone issue

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I've just begun cocos2d development on the iphone. An issue I'm having is that when I add a CCSprite to my scene, instead of it being transparent around the edges of the .png file, its showing up as white.

So for example, I define the CCSprite in my header file -

```
 CCSprite *foo;
```

Then when I initialise my scene -

```
  foo = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"foo.png"];

  [self addChild:player z:0 tag:1];
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thanks for any help.

P.S. I have double checked my .png file in Photoshop and its correctly showing up as transparent where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the bottom portion of this page:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/faq#my_png_doesn_t_look_like_in_photoshop

Comment: I am seeing this issue only with devices that have iOS 5.0 and higher ... images appear fine with iOS below 5.